# jQuery is calling my live("keydown") event multiple times after .load()

Tags: jquery, keydown

I have the following jQuery event:

```
$("#scanItem").live("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```

scanItem is a textbox in my page.

The first time I load the page, everything works fine.  Pressing enter fires the event exactly 1 time.  However, I have a dropdown that will do a jQuery load to re-load the div.

After the div reloads, when I press enter on the textbox, the alert fires 3 times.

I've been scratching my brain for hours on this.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Is this script in the reloaded div ? BTW live is deprecated (or removed, depending on the versions).

Comment: Can you show the code you use to reload the div? It's possible that there are multiple listeners being created and not removed when reloading.

Comment: Show the jquery code for the dropdown

Comment: I believe if someone holds the key then `keydown` fires more than once. Use `keypress`

Comment: @dystroy: Yes, the script is reloaded.

Comment: @DigTheDoug: $("#detailList").load("@Url.Action("_QCDetailListPartial")?salesOrderID=@(Model.SalesOrder.SalesOrderID)&generateQC=false");

Comment: use bind instead of live

Comment: If the script is reloaded, then you're adding event handlers each time.

Comment: @Cfreak - Holding down keys fires multiple `keypress` events too, but if the handler throws up an alert the user has to close the alert and then press the key again. (Though if they hold down the enter key that closes the alert and triggers the next `keypress` event on the page.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the script is reloaded, then you're adding event handlers each time.

An easy solution, if you can't move the script out of the div, would be to change it to not use `live` :

```
$("#scanItem").on('keydown', function (e) {
```

To make it work you must ensure the code is after the `#scanItem` element.

So this wouldn't touch future elements with the same id.

By the way, as `live` was deprecated and is now removed from new versions, you really should use `on` instead, directly (like here) or by delegation (which makes it functionally equivalent to `live`).

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  I moved the scripts to the parent view and everything is working peachy now.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#scanItem").unbind().on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('hi');
    }
});
```